# Sort files by name

Tags: scala, sorting

How can I sort in ascending/descending order a group of files based on their name with the following naming convention: `myPath\numberTheFileInt.ext`?

I would like to obtain something like the following:

```
myPath\1.csv
myPath\02.csv
...
myPath\21.csv
...
myPath\101.csv
```

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
myFiles = getFiles(myFilesDirectory).sortWith(_.getName < _.getName)
```

Despite the files being sorted in the directory, they are unsorted in `myFiles`.
I have in output:

```
myPath\1.csv
myPath\101.csv
myPath\02.csv
...
myPath\21.csv
```

I tried multiple things but it always throws an `NoSuchElementException`.

Has anyone already done this?

Comment: You'll have to parse the number that is part of the file name and sort based on that, rather than on the natural ordering of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing strings would yield an order based on unicode values of the strings being compared. What you need is to extract the file number and order based on that as an Integer.

```
import java.io.File

val extractor = "([\\d]+).csv$".r

val files = List(
  "myPath/1.csv",
  "myPath/101.csv",
  "myPath/02.csv",
  "myPath/21.csv",
  "myPath/33.csv"
).map(new File(_))


val sorted = files.sortWith {(l, r) =>
  val extractor(lFileNumber) = l.getName
  val extractor(rFileNumber) = r.getName

  lFileNumber.toInt < rFileNumber.toInt
}

sorted.foreach(println)
```

Results:

```
myPath/1.csv
myPath/02.csv
myPath/21.csv
myPath/33.csv
myPath/101.csv
```

**UPDATE**

An alternative as proposed by @dhg

```
val sorted = files.sortBy { f => f.getName match {
  case extractor(n) => n.toInt
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner version of J.Romero's answer, using `sortBy`:

```
val Extractor = "([\\d]+)\\.csv".r
val sorted = files.map(_.getName).sortBy{ case Extractor(n) => n.toInt }
```

Comment: As I would like to use the most clean way to do the job, I am interested in your method the most; but it returns `sorted: List[String]` due to the `map(_.getName)`. Would you have an update to retrieve: `sorted: List[File]`?

Comment: Update the answer with the working version of @dhg's proposal.